# how to change the location of the marginals of the jointgrid along with color for the marginals

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting a particle beam phase-space using jointgrid.  Currently I am doing this:

```
g = sns.JointGrid(t_mm_scaled,p_scaled, space=0)
g.plot_marginals(sns.kdeplot, shade=True)
g.plot_joint(sns.kdeplot, shade=True, cmap="jet", n_levels=40);
```

My goal is plot the marginals "inside" the plotting area (the big box).

a] The top marginal plot should be moved to the bottom and the right plot to the left and everything should be inside the center box.  I really need a projection inside the box. Also the x-projection should be in red and y in yellow. I have a dark background inside the plot for comparison with a camera.

b] Also, instead of pearson coefficient, I need a simple RMS of the x and y-distribution to be displayed inside the plot. I am sure this is possible but I am unable to find the classic "rms","fwhm","sigma" function instead of writing one.

Help appreciated. First post to StackOverflow.

Comment: While it might be possible to hack `JointGrid` to get this to work, I suspect it will very likely be easier to just use `kdeplot` on one Axes, using `twinx` and `twiny to place and scale the marginal plots properly.

Comment: mwaskom, can you elaborate on the twinx part. I am not sure how to combine marginals and twinx? Thanks!